# C++ - On friend assignment-operator overloads

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I’ve been experimenting with creating code interfaces with C++ classes.

And a puzzling thing that came up in testing is overloading assignment operators.
Take a look at the code below:

```
struct my_object {
  // This doesn't work. :(
  friend int& operator =(int& variable, my_object object)
  { variable = object.value; return variable; }

  // This works, but `int value; value <<= my_object{};` 
  // for `int value; value = my_object{};` doesn't seem clean...
  friend int& operator <<=(int& variable, my_object object)
  { variable = object.value; return variable; }
};
```

---

My confusion is: 
The first overload does not compile and logs this error to the console terminal.

```
'friend int& operator =(int&, my_object)' must be a nonstatic member function
```

But then, the second overload compiles with no errors (or warnings) whatsoever despite being near identical to the first one.

---

Why is the first operator overload invalid and the second one seemingly fine (at least by the *GCC 6.3.0* compiler)?

Comment: I can understand why the first overload shouldn't work, it doesn't seem clean to be able to overload operators for POD types like `int`. But the second overload, why is this one accepted by the compiler (it may or may not be standard AFAIK)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=`, `()` (function call), and `[]` operators are required to be members of the class. Other operators generally are allowed to be either members or non-members.

It follows that the only time when you can overload the assignment operator is when defining the class on the left-hand side. There is no way to write a custom assignment operator whose left-hand argument is a non-class type.

In order to assign `my_object` to `int`, you need to write a conversion function instead:

```
struct my_object {
    operator int() const { return value; }
    // ...
    int value;
};
```

Comment: The take-away here is that `=`, `()` and `[]` operators *must* be non-static members of a class (unlike other operators).